# How could Eisenheim achieve those reflections on the scene in that era?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, the-illusionist

In [The Illusionist (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443543/), how could Eisenheim achieve those reflections (visions) on the scene? Even in one of the scenes, there was a (ghost) boy walking through the audience. Given that the film takes place in early 1900s, were that kind of illusions possible in that era?

[image: scr1]
[image: scr2]

Comment: I wonder if this would be a better fit on Physics if you're looking for a real-world type of explanation

Comment: I think the question still fits Movies.SE. Would you mind keeping it open for a while to see the answers?

Comment: oh of course, not going to close it because of an opinion, was just wondering what kind of aspect you wanted this answered in is all :)

Comment: I am curious whether the reflections are reasonable. I don't want to believe it could be a goof :)

Comment: Interesting question, I've wondered this myself, but I'm afraid this is one of those things I would attribute to "movie magic" and thus not being possible in real-life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magical performances comprising of spirits being summoned on stage where pretty common even in the 19th century. The effect was achieved indeed with the use of *smoke and mirror*. However, a typical tool in usage was the [Fantascope aka Magic Lantern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_lantern). This apparatus is also seen in the movie but can be easily overlooked as normal lanterns.

I found this interesting piece of [trivia](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443543/trivia?tab=tr&item=tr1865795) on IMDB:

> The method for creating the ghosts as shown to inspector Uhl involved the projection of a pre-recorded image into a hazy background. Since the ghosts Eisenheim conjured could speak to and interact with the audience, he most likely used a different method popular among magicians at that time. A fantascope was used to illuminate a real person off stage. The image was reflected off of a mirror or glassplate, creating a ghosted image. The lanterns that Eisenheim tells his assistants to leave behind when they are packing up the workshop bear a strong resemblance to fantascopes.

Comment: Indeed - angled mirrors were used extensively in early film making to superimpose images into scenes, something Coppola recreated for his take on Dracula.

Answer (score 13):

It's suggested in the movie itself that these illusions are possible. A couple of performers (perhaps) demonstrate to the inspector how it could be done using what would be called *Smoke and Mirrors (S&M)* today. It can be surmised that Eisenheim perfected the technique and used it for his illusion.